# Java, serve HLS live video streams

Tags: java, ffmpeg, video-streaming, red5, wowza

I know the topic is not an easy one, but I am looking for a Java class to send an HLS stream from the server to the client.

I have files being generated greater and greater:

```
out.m3u8
out0.ts
out1.ts
out2.ts
out3.ts
out4.ts
out5.ts
out6.ts
```

This is generated using ffmpeg from an original source:

```
ffmpeg -i http://sourceurl.com:9981/stream/channel/1232131 out.m3u8
```

I can play it using VLC.

Somehow, I need to stream this **live** to the clients.

At this point, I do not really care about different bit rates, i just want live streaming to work, in mobile browsers and on desktop browsers.

I found this class:

```
https://github.com/Red5/red5-hls-plugin/blob/master/plugin/src/main/java/org/red5/stream/http/servlet/PlayList.java
```

Which might be doing something like that.

I have pulled in hls.js into my application in hopes of using it for desktops.

HLS should however work IOS devices without hls.js right now.

How should one serve HLS content from the server? It's very difficult to find any good and simple example to do that.

**Anyone knows of the steps needed to do that ?**

I've looked into Wowza and Red5 just a little bit, but unsure what they can provide for me at this stage and seems to be overly complicated to setup just to serve some files. But please explain to me why that's not the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The H in HLS stands for HTTP. The point of streaming tech such as HLS DASH HDS smooth streaming, etc is that no special server is necessary. Just plain HTTP. you can use something like nginx, or any HTTP server class/library available for Java or any other language.

Comment: do you mind elaborating? So normally i get like out.m3u8 file, and then a rolling out10.ts out11.ts and so on files ... I would need to somehow open them up and serve them to the client. Is it simply just serving the bytes, and when there is no more bytes in one, go on to the next one? Or will I need to read the out.m3u8 and handle some kind of protocol? I am not sure to be honest, but I would like to do it in java and not nginx to get full control.

Comment: You don't do anything with the files. Just host them. Post a link to the m3u8 file over http. The player will do http gets and pull the files as it needs them.

Comment: This person wants to stream "live" via HLS; standard HTTP servers don't do this. Red5 allows you to stream to the server and have it served via HLS and actually Red5 Pro has this in a working package.

Comment: For reference live HLS means the m3u8 and ts files are NOT static.

Comment: You guys are cracking me up. I develop the HLS system at twitch.tv. In 2015, we delivered 241,441,823,059 minutes of LIVE video using HLS over standard HTTP. So, yes I can unequivocally say standard HTTP servers do do this.

Comment: @szatmary I wouldn't know, but the question is if I serve the first m3u8, from say a controller/action, where does subsequent request come into? I still have to serve them somehow, right? Can you shed some light on that? Is there a special url pattern one has to abide with? For instance, /tv/watch/channel123.m3u8 ... will subsequent requests out57.ts come to /tv/watch/.... ?? Am I making any sense? So maybe it is not as simple as you stated, because maybe you assume nginx or apache manages this for you. Maybe I should rely on them too,

Comment: ... but I am curious as to how I can serve them through a servlet I control.

Comment: Also, you have to set the appropiate headers for the response, correct? What would the appropiate headers be?

Comment: HLS is pull based, you simply make the files available. The brains are in the player. The player knows when it needs more video. The player will connect the the server and ask for the next file. You don't need to feed it. You don't need any headers beyond what is required by HTTP.

Comment: The player know what files to request, because they are listed  in the m3u8. (you can view the m3u8 in any ascii editor). The m3u8 is updated every time a new ts file appears. The player polls the server checking to see if the m3u8 was updated. If it was, It will download the next ts file listed in the m3u8.

Comment: Its not tit-4-tat @szatmary but you dont indicate to the poster as to how the m3u8 can be modified in a live sense. I've been in the video streaming game since 1998 btw, seen a lot come and go; static http isn't always the best answer.

Comment: The m3u8 is being modified by ffmpeg automatically in this case. So I felt that did not need to be explained. And I agree http is not always the best answer. But this question is specifically about http.

Comment: Momo started out using a servlet which in the default case doesnt actually write an m3u8, so at a lower level its more dynamic http, but I think we both know wth we're talking about here.

Comment: Sorry guys, I think I am following you somewhat here, but not 100%. Yes, I will be generating the m3u8 using ffmpeg and it is dynamic and will continue to change. I hope it is as you say szatmary that the player will make the necessary request and i think it is relative to the original m3u8 location. I will try that tomorrow. But I also want to ask you about if you think my attempted solution ( over http ) is no good?

Comment: Is it because of TCP? Is there a way to make the player make UDP calls instead? And I know Paul is one of the main authors for Red5 HLS plugin, so you both have valuable input here. I will try this approach out tomorrow, and report back. I hope you don't abandon me :)

Comment: HTTP is always TCP (unless your using google quic, but we'll ignore that for now).

Comment: @szatmary And as you stated H in HLS stands for HTTP, there is little change of getting it to UDP?

Also, here is an except and its content in hastebin: 

http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8

http://hastebin.com/jivilaxili.avrasm

As you can see at the bottom the file fileSequence19.ts can be downloaded relative to the gear url. I am just wondering, when the player requests fileSequence19.ts, will it also send along which original file it was refering to? If I have many streams on the server, then I need to associate fileSequence19.ts with ...

Comment: ... with the right, and original m3u8. I know, I am getting ahead of myself, I need to test this tomorrow. But already started thinking of how to approach this.

Comment: The client always sends the full path to the server, you do not need to track it, just keep the file in the same directory. in your example the client will request `devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/fileSequence19.ts`   HTTP is TCP.

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking that fileSequence19 or out1.ts is not unique. So if I have two live streams, one for http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8

and one for 

http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/pingpong.m3u8

and both contains fileSequence19.ts 

I won't be able to know which is actually requested. But I guess if I add a a url part before i might as the part up to pingpong.m3u8 seems to remain intact in subsequent requests. I need a full day to implement this and will attempt this tomorrow. It's good to have gotten some pointers to wake up for :)

Comment: It appears as if this is indeed working. Was very simple. Less than 4 lines of code in total :)

Comment: @momomo It would be great if you wrote a blog post/answer which illustrates how you eventually went about the final solution with some sample code. I am facing the same issue that you did and finding very little content online to precisely help me through it.

Comment: @AbhishekNandgaonkar I don't even remember the problem.

Comment: @AbhishekNandgaonkar I think it's just a matter of adding an extra url pattern prior to the .m3u8 request, and then then ts files will have request the same base url.